# How to retrieve only 1 photo from Picasa using Google API with Asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, picasa

Is it possible to retrieve just one photo from picasa. I am looking around on the web and the documentation and I have yet to see an example, There is one post on here that came close but gave a half answer which I already knew. Please help, thank you.

I have gotten this far, I need to know what to do next. I am getting a bad request error.

```
query = New PhotoQuery(PicasaQuery.CreatePicasaUri(username, albumID, photoID))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution after more research. Do not query for album and album id just the photo.
http://markmail.org/message/dbtoym57matzxjmd

```
 PicasaEntry entry = (PicasaEntry) service.Getstring.Format("http://picasaweb.google.com/data/entry/api/user/" +
                                                      "{0}/photoid/{1}",service.Credentials.Username,photo.GooglePhotoId
```